# Prevent deselect a row after clicked same row second time on a b-table

Tags: bootstrap-vue

how to prevent deselect a row from a bootstrap b-table?
at intialial state, no rows selected, but after the table is clicked, there is at least and at most 1 row selected.  By default, clicking a row 2nd time, it will be deselected. I hope the selected row is still highlighted.

This table is not read-only, instead cells are given editors to support editing, so when current editing row is clicked again, the row must be still highlighted to support cell-editor's events fired correctly.

**Background**:
This is my template code, cell editor definition is injected via **"<slot name="columns" />"**, and is initialized / cached in '**fields**' during '**created**' hook.

Method clicked() just write down current row index and process data, when current highlight row is clicked twice, its focus lost.

Sample layout:
[image]

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table ref="ui" :items="val" :fields="fields" responsive sticky-header head-variant="dark" :striped="true"
      selectable select-mode="single" @row-clicked="clicked"
      :data-meta="$attrs.name" v-bind="{...$attrs}" data-ui="16" :style="style"  class="w-100 mx-0"
      v-contextmenu:ctxMenu >

      <slot name="events" />
      <slot name="columns" />

      <template #table-colgroup="scope">
        <col v-for="(field, index) in scope.fields" :key="field.key" :style="field.visible ? index > 0 && field.sz === undefined ? null : (index == 0 ? 'nowrap: nowrap' : ('width: ' +  field.sz + 'ch!important'))  : 'width: 0!important'" />
      </template>

      <template v-for="(field, index) in fields"   v-slot:[cell(field.key)] = "row">
        <table :key="index" :style="index == 0 ? 'width: 20ch' : null" v-if="index == 0" style="p-0">
          <tbody>
            <tr  @click="clickTreeRow(row.index, row.item)">
              <td class="m-0 p-0">
                <a  :key="index" v-if="index === 0"  variant="primary" href="#" @click.prevent="switchNode(row.item)"  :style="'padding-left:' + row.item.level + 'em'" >
                  <b-icon :icon="row.item.children.length == 0 ? '' : row.item.expand ? 'folder-minus' : 'folder-plus'"/>
                </a>
              </td>
              <td style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap"  class="m-0 p-0">
                <ui-text     :key="'c' + row.index + '_' + field.key" :name="field.key" :type="field.type" :data-options="colOpt(field.key)" :data-default="colDef(field.key)" :data-param="colParam(field.key)" :layout="colLayout(field.key)" :sz="field.sz" :scale="field.scale" :data-row="row.index" @click="clicked(row, row.index)" @change="change" :cellEvents="columnEvents[field.key]" :class="fieldClazz" v-if="field.ui=='2'" />
                <ui-combo    :key="'c' + row.index + '_' + field.key" :name="field.key" :data-options="colOpt(field.key)" :data-default="colDef(field.key)" :data-param="colParam(field.key)" :layout="colLayout(field.key)" :sz="field.sz" :data-row="row.index" @click="clicked(row, row.index)" @change="change" :cellEvents="columnEvents[field.key]" :class="fieldClazz" v-else-if="field.ui === '9'" />
                <ui-check    :key="'c' + row.index + '_' + field.key" :name="field.key" :data-default="colDef(field.key)" :data-param="colParam(field.key)" :layout="colLayout(field.key)" :sz="field.sz" :data-row="row.index" @click="clicked(row, row.index)" @change="change" :cellEvents="columnEvents[field.key]" :class="checkClazz" v-else-if="field.ui === '12'" />
                <ui-calendar :key="'c' + row.index + '_' + field.key" :name="field.key" :data-default="colDef(field.key)" :data-param="colParam(field.key)" :layout="colLayout(field.key)" :sz="field.sz" :data-row="row.index" @click="clicked(row, row.index)" @change="change" :cellEvents="columnEvents[field.key]" :class="fieldClazz" v-else-if="field.ui =='36'" />
                <ui-textarea :key="'c' + row.index + '_' + field.key" :name="field.key" :data-default="colDef(field.key)" :data-param="colParam(field.key)" :layout="colLayout(field.key)" :sz="field.sz" :data-row="row.index" @click="clicked(row, row.index)" @change="change" :cellEvents="columnEvents[field.key]" :class="fieldClazz" v-else-if="field.ui =='10'" />
                <ui-label    :key="'c' + row.index + '_' + field.key" :name="field.key" :type="field.type" :layout="colLayout(field.key)" :sz="field.sz" :data-row="row.index" @click="clicked(row, index)" :class="fieldClazz" v-else />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <ui-text     :key="'c' + row.index + '_' + field.key" :name="field.key" :type="field.type" :data-options="colOpt(field.key)" :data-default="colDef(field.key)" :data-param="colParam(field.key)" :layout="colLayout(field.key)" :sz="field.sz" :data-row="row.index" @click="clicked(row, row.index)" @change="change" :cellEvents="columnEvents[field.key]" :class="fieldClazz" v-if="index > 0 && field.ui=='2'" />
        <ui-combo    :key="'c' + row.index + '_' + field.key" :name="field.key" :data-options="colOpt(field.key)" :data-default="colDef(field.key)" :data-param="colParam(field.key)" :layout="colLayout(field.key)" :sz="field.sz" :data-row="row.index" @click="clicked(row, row.index)" @change="change" :cellEvents="columnEvents[field.key]" :class="fieldClazz" v-else-if="index > 0 && field.ui === '9'" />
        <ui-check    :key="'c' + row.index + '_' + field.key" :name="field.key" :data-default="colDef(field.key)" :data-param="colParam(field.key)" :layout="colLayout(field.key)" :sz="field.sz" :data-row="row.index" @click="clicked(row, row.index)" @change="change" :cellEvents="columnEvents[field.key]" :class="checkClazz" v-else-if="index > 0 && field.ui === '12'" />
        <ui-calendar :key="'c' + row.index + '_' + field.key" :name="field.key" :data-default="colDef(field.key)" :data-param="colParam(field.key)" :layout="colLayout(field.key)" :sz="field.sz" :data-row="row.index" @click="clicked(row, row.index)" @change="change" :cellEvents="columnEvents[field.key]" :class="fieldClazz" v-else-if="index > 0 && field.ui =='36'" />
        <ui-textarea :key="'c' + row.index + '_' + field.key" :name="field.key" :data-default="colDef(field.key)" :data-param="colParam(field.key)" :layout="colLayout(field.key)" :sz="field.sz" :data-row="row.index" @click="clicked(row, row.index)" @change="change" :cellEvents="columnEvents[field.key]" :class="fieldClazz" v-else-if="index > 0 && field.ui =='10'" />
        <ui-label    :key="'c' + row.index + '_' + field.key" :name="field.key" :type="field.type" :layout="colLayout(field.key)" :sz="field.sz" :data-row="row.index" @click="clicked(row, index)" :class="fieldClazz" v-else-if="index > 0" />

      </template>

    </b-table>

    <v-contextmenu ref="ctxMenu" theme="dark">
      <v-contextmenu-item @click="addNode()" :disabled="availableActions[0] === false">+</v-contextmenu-item>
      <v-contextmenu-item @click="removeNode()" :disabled="availableActions[1] === false">-</v-contextmenu-item>

      <v-contextmenu-item divider></v-contextmenu-item>
      <v-contextmenu-item @click="move('U')" :disabled="availableActions[2] === false">↑</v-contextmenu-item>
      <v-contextmenu-item @click="move('D')" :disabled="availableActions[3] === false">↓</v-contextmenu-item>
      <v-contextmenu-item @click="move('L')" :disabled="availableActions[4] === false">←</v-contextmenu-item>
      <v-contextmenu-item @click="move('R')" :disabled="availableActions[5] === false">→</v-contextmenu-item>
    </v-contextmenu>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
```

Comment: Could you please share what you've done already in your code?

Comment: @ImanShafiei , no special processing, just use its built-in properties,  
selectable  select-mode="single"